# R language: how to use ggplot2 to plot multiple vectors on one graph with regression lines?

Tags: r, ggplot2

If I have the following data frame (DF) for example, how to use ggplot2 to graph VAR1 versus year, and VAR2 versus year, in one graph? And add regression lines?

```
year  VAR1  VAR2
2001    10    12
2002    30    12
2003    20    15
```

I can get one graph using `qplot(year, VAR, data=DF, geom=c("point", "smooth"), method="lm", se=FALSE)`, but not sure how to add the other one. Do I need to rearrange the data somehow to have factors, then use the `facets` attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to gather `VAR1` and `VAR2` into the same column first, which can be done using the `gather` function in the [tidyr](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/07/22/introducing-tidyr/) package:

```
library(tidyr)
DF2 <- gather(DF, type, value, VAR1, VAR2)
```

This will make DF2 tidy, with one row for each point you want on the plot (see [this paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v59/i10/paper) for more about tidy data and the gathering manipulation):

```
  year type value
1 2001 VAR1    10
2 2002 VAR1    30
3 2003 VAR1    20
4 2001 VAR2    12
5 2002 VAR2    12
6 2003 VAR2    15
```

Once you've done this, you can create the plot with both variables using:

```
ggplot(DF2, aes(year, value, color = type)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

If you'd prefer to separate the VARs into two subplots (facets), you could instead do:

```
ggplot(DF2, aes(year, value)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
    facet_wrap(~ type)
```